# How to connect to a .mdb or .accdb with C# using Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, mono

I have an app developed in Visual Studio and this uses MS Access DB and C#, now I need to migrate it to Linux, I'm trying to use the same database, but for now I receive this message *"the .Net Framework Data Providers requiere Microsoft Data Access Components(mdac)"*. I used .Net portability analyzer to detect what is supported in mono what's not, and everything apears to be supported. I have read mono database access but the only option it gives is through MDB tools.

I have read about MDB Tools http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/ but it's still in a development stage, is there another alternative or I need to use another database manager like SQLite?

Comment: what operating system do you want to use when using Mono?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 - 16.04 LTS) @knocte

Comment: are you aware that MS Access doesn't run on Linux?

Comment: Yes, but I don't need to open the .accdb or .mdb file from MS Access, I just need to connect to it from c# to do CRUD operations, and that's what till now I can't achieve, do you know whether is there a data providerfor MS Access Database ? Or SQLite could be an alternative to store the data. @knocte